# How to time how long it took for Postgres to actually execute in query using Knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

How to time how long it took for Postgres to actually execute in query using Knex? Is there a way to do this?

Ideally, I'd like to see a breakdown of timings like: time to acquire socket from pool, time for PG to execute query, time to receive bytes.

Comment: There are a [debug](http://knexjs.org/#Installation-debug) option in `knex` and `DEBUG=knex:* node path/to/your/app.js` options for debugging. With timings. Not sure if this covers all of your desires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your app with environment variable `DEBUG=knex:*` and it will print lots of info about how long certain things took.

Also you can add event handlers to query events http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Events and do your own timers there. Those events can be also set globally like `knex.on('query', ...)`.